# Graph function step by step and paint

Tags: plotting

I am trying to graph the following function for $r_0 = 2.1 m$

$$ \begin{align*} \alpha(r_0) = \begin{cases} \pi - \arcsin (3
sqrt{3} \sqrt{1 - 2 m/r_0}/r_0), & \text{for } 2m < r_0 \leq 3m, \\
\arcsin (3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{1 - 2 m/r_0}/r_0), & \text{for } r_0 \geq
3m, \end{cases} \end{align*} $$

I wrote in mathematics the following:
[image: code]

But I can't get the graph I expect (Figure 2 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.07101v2)).

[image: shadow]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the code in text form.

Answer (score 0):

```
PieChart[#,ChartStyle -> {Orange, Black}] & /@ 
{{1, 4}, {2, 6}, {4, 9}}
```

(and put in your numbers)